# TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlacesService' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-places-api

My objective is to request a group of locations that fit my criteria using a "routeRequest" and save them. In order to to that, I was to use google Places to check the locations around the center of my map.

```
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector("#myMap"), {
    center: { lat: 41.148481, lng: -8.606893 },
    zoom: 15
  });

let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(routeRequest, callback);


let routeRequest = {
    location: map.center,
    radius: '1000',
    type: [this.typeRoute]
  };


function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (const result of results) {
        this.listLocations.push(result);
      }
    }
  }
```

The issue is, placesService doens't seem to recognize the map

Comment: You can't access that property until the callback has run. Move your assignment into the `if` check after it's returned successfully.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter What do you mean as "assignment"? Should I move "service=new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)" into the callback function? If I do that, it tells me "service" is undefined and that "google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)" is defined but not used.

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: Do you have the places library loaded in your bootstrap URL a la <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: @ecg8 I'm loading the places api and the rest of the API's using my API key, in my Index.html page.

Comment: @evan Sorry evan, i'm kinda new to this. How can I do that?

Comment: No worries! These are online IDEs where you can add working code and share it publicly. E.g. https://codesandbox.io/ or https://stackblitz.com/ You can use these platforms to build a minimal reproducible sample of your app that you can then share with us so that we can help.

Comment: For simple apps there's also https://jsfiddle.net/ and http://jsbin.com/?html,output

Comment: @evan here is the link for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-mendeleev-3i3r9. You need to add an API Key to it though. With google maps API and google Places API.

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look at it and get back to you. I gotta work on someone else's issue first today.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are getting this error because you haven't loaded the [places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library). In `index.html` you have this Maps API script:

```
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
```

Add the following:

```
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places"></script>
```

Hope this helps!